# A Simple Tool to Train and Test Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network

I’m looking a simple tool to train and test neural networks for classification tasks. It need not be very sophisticated tool and I just want to train and test simple data sets such as given in the following web site.

http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/PRNN/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a pre-made utility, but you could roll your own quite quickly using the [Encog](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog) neural network framework (for both Java and .NET).

I've used it before and it was quite easy to get to grips with. The documentation is quite good, and if you need it, I've also found support on the forums to be good.

*** UPDATE ***

I just remembered that Encog does actually ship with a pre-made utility called [Encog Workbench](https://github.com/downloads/encog/encog-dotnet-core/encog-workbench-3.0.0-release.zip), which should do what you want.